# How to parse double list JSON data in c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I am getting JSON data by calling a service which format like :

```
[
  [
    {
      "AgentStatus": "- Active",
      "Basement": "None",
      "BasementType": "",
      "Baths": "4",
      "BathsHalf": "1",
      "Beds": "6"
    },
    [
      "372010-1.jpg"
    ]
  ],
  [
    {
      "AgentStatus": "- Active",
      "Basement": "Finished,Full",
      "BasementType": "FULL FINISHED",
      "Baths": "2",
      "BathsHalf": "1",
      "Beds": "3"
    },
    [
      "377388-1.jpg",
      "377388-2.jpg",
      "377388-12.jpg"
    ]
  ]
]
```

To parse this JSON i made class like :

```
public class RetsProperty
{
    public PropertyAttributes PropAttributes { get; set; }

    public string[] ImgUrls { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyAttributes
{
    public string AgentStatus { get; set; }

    public string Basement { get; set; }

    public string BasementType { get; set; }

    public string Baths { get; set; }

    public string BathsHalf { get; set; }

    public string Beds { get; set; }
}
```

And i have used Newtonsoft Json to deserialize JSON data

```
var retsPropertyItems = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RetsProperty>>(propertyJsonString);
```

But it can't parse it returns below error :

[image]

**I think it is because i can't able to create class properly.**

**So how can i format my class ?
Or is it possible to map the way i did ?**

Thanks

Comment: Is this json supposed to be a list of `RetsProperty`?, the json seems malformed to me (looks to be giving a 2d array of objects)

Comment: Do you have access to JSON? Change inner array to object

Comment: No, I've not any access. I am getting it from a service call.

Comment: You might struggle then basically you have a 2d array with an `PropertyAttributes` object and an array of strings, with one object in each array (`[ [ PropertyAttributes, [strings] ], [ PropertyAttributes, [strings] ] ]`), Its probably still doable, its just not as easy as getting a single list of `RetsProperty`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have really bad formatted **JSON** becouse it have array within array without property name. So you just should parse it carefully.

I came up with a solution that could be not so bad and easy to understand (If i understand your **JSON** format right). The idea is to wrap your **JSON** with property name and then parse his constuction.

You should wrap your **JSON** same way:

```
var wrappedText = @"{ ""Prop"": " + propertyJsonString + " }";
```

And then you can parse in with **Newtonsoft Json**:

```
var jsonData = JObject.Parse(wrappedText);
```

Now you have your **JSON** data and you should parse it manualy. I recommend you this way:

```
List<RetsProperty> RetsProperties = new List<RetsProperty>();
foreach (var prop in jsonData["Prop"])
{
    RetsProperties.Add(new RetsProperty
        {
            ImgUrls = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(prop.Last.ToString()),
            PropAttributes = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PropertyAttributes>(prop.First.ToString())
        });
};
```

You should understand that i**t will work only if you have 2 array items in last array**. Take a look at `prop.First` and `prop.Last`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have a very strange JSON, but as you said you receive it from external service. You can parse such JSON using [`JArray`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) and [`LINQ`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx), but of course this method is very dependent on the structure of JSON.

```
var retsProperties = JArray.Parse(json)
    .Select(item => new RetsProperty
    {
        PropAttributes = item.First.ToObject<PropertyAttributes>(),
        ImgUrls = item.Last.ToObject<string[]>()
    })
    .ToList();
```